# How to pass explicitly the Blazor's "KeyboardEventArgs" to C# method?

Tags: c#, razor, blazor

I need the C#/Blazor equivalent for the method `onKeyDown` of the following Vue class component:

```js
import { Vue, Component, Prop } from "nuxt-property-decorator";


@Component()
export default class TextBox extends Vue implements ValidatableControl {

  @Prop({ type: Boolean, default: false }) 
  private readonly valueMustBeNonNegativeIntegerOfRegularNotation!: boolean;
  @Prop({ type: Boolean, default: false }) 
  private readonly valueMustBeDigitsSequence!: boolean;

  protected onKeyDown(event: KeyboardEvent): void {
    if ((this.valueMustBeNonNegativeIntegerOfRegularNotation || this.valueMustBeDigitsSequence) && /^[+\-e.]$/u.test(event.key)) {
      event.preventDefault();
    }
  }

}
```

AFAIK there is no imperative API similar to `event.preventDefault` in Blazor.
However, we use the declarative API from the Razor template:

```xml
<textarea
  @onkeydown:preventDefault=@(args => mustPreventOnKeyDownEvent(args))
></textarea>
```

Where the `mustPreventOnKeyDownEvent` is the method of class component:

```cs
public partial class TextBox : InputtableControl, IValidatableControl
{

  [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Parameter]  
  public bool valueMustBeTheDigitsSequence { get; set; } = false;  

  private bool mustPreventOnKeyDownEvent(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web.KeyboardEventArgs keyboardEventArguments) =>
      (this.valueMustBeTheNonNegativeIntegerOfRegularNotation || this.valueMustBeTheDigitsSequence) &&
      new Regex("^[+\\-e.]$").IsMatch(keyboardEventArguments.Key);

}
```

Current I have the error

> The delegate type could not be inferred

at `@onkeydown:preventDefault=@(args => mustPreventOnKeyDownEvent(args))`. How to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

I am not completely sure what you trying to achieve, but you prevent default "modifier" is for setting bool values:

```
<textarea @onkeydown:preventDefault="true" 
          @onkeydown="@(args => mustPreventOnKeyDownEvent(args))">
</textarea>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Just in case, I'll tell what I doing. When either `valueMustBeTheNonNegativeIntegerOfRegularNotation` or `valueMustBeTheDigitsSequence` is true, the inputting of character `e` must be prevented.